# Which one to use here if/when or neither?

Tags: modal-verbs, future-tense

> If I study well I'll get an A+

Or

> When I study well I'll get an A+

I want to say that presently I'm studying well so I'll certainly get an A+

So I'm sceptical about both

Because if is used for possible or unreal situations

And when is used with future constructions which are certain.

So i guess these both wont work here

But when also mean considering that

So i guess in that case when can be used for present

> When(considering that) I study well(presently). I'll definitely get an A+

Answer (score 1):

Neither "if" nor "when" is enough in this case on their own to express what you want. Instead, you need to use a future continuous construction that adds in a few other words to explain the continuation. Here's a good way to say it:

> If I **keep studying** well I'll get an A+

"If" is still there, since you do need to express uncertainty, but now the uncertainty is clearer: whether or not you'll "keep" (persist, continue) a present state, backed up by the continuous tense in the gerund form of the original verb "study".

You can't really do the same thing with "when", since it expresses a certain relationship. The only thing you could say is

> When I study well I [always] get an A+

This expresses present *habit* based on past experience that can plausibly be extended into the future. But it strongly implies that you've had enough experience studying well and getting A+ accordingly that you're confident in the pattern, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: Yeah. I never thought it this way .

Comment: Btw can't I use when for present.  When(considering that,in the view of the fact) I study well(currently) I'll definitely get an A+

Comment: @user236989: Addressed that, I think.